# Cannot access local sites from mobile phone while connected to LAN

Tags: networking, apache-2.4, lamp

I have Apache setup on an Ubuntu machine, and I have two sites created. I can access both of them from the localhost machine via the domain names. The problem is that I cannot access them via my Android phone. The most important one at the moment is lazyjoe.lan (shown below), which is going to be an app that the family will be able to use while connected to the LAN.

Here is my /etc/hosts file to show the two domain names in question:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   HAL #<-- COMPUTER'S NAME
127.0.0.1   devsocialhub.com #<-- THIS ONE
127.0.0.1   lazyjoe.lan #<-- AND THIS ONE


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Here is the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/lazyjoe.lan.conf file (comments removed to keep it short)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName lazyjoe.lan
    DocumentRoot /var/www/lazyjoe.lan/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I make it where:
1) I can access these sites via smart phone? 
2) I can access them via the domain name rather than IP address since both sites are from the same IP? Typing in the IP on my phone only shows devsocialhub.com

I've tried to find answers, but I keep getting WAMP and XAMPP questions, and their answers aren't helping me solve this. Any help is appreciated, and if you need more info, I'll gladly give it.

**NOTE** devsocialhub.com is owned by myself, and it's registered through a domain registrar, but it is not publicly viewable yet. If this is affecting my ability to access it from my phone, I am unaware of why or how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's not publicly viewable, that would explain why you can't view it. As for the other domain, you need to have it exist in DNS in order to be able to access it other than from a computer with a hosts entry for it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as though the answer to your question is basically to ensure DNS records are available.

Specifically, you probably need to set something like `dnsmasq` on your LAN router (or if you use some access point with limited options, create a DNS server on your LAN, and make your DHCP server push that DNS server to LAN client), and make sure you have a DNS record for your LAN hosts.

On the face of it, your Apache setup seems fine, and your description of the issue very much seems to point to an issue with DNS (i.e. the mechanism to map names to IPs) - so you should be able to just set up a LAN-only DNS server, and get the functionality you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will look into how to do that on my router and come back to accept if it works.